# Can i filter the custom post type items by the URL parameter values?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

URL:- `abcdefghi/?state=18&district=DistrictName`

I have a URL as I mentioned above, and I want to filter my Custom Post Type items by these parameters. I also have advanced custom fields for each item that contain the same values in the URL (state&district)

I just want the result as state & district filtered,

I used the meta_query method, but I didn't get any solution,

the below code is that I tried for the solution

```
$state = $_GET["state"];
        $district = $_GET["district"];

        echo $state;
        echo $district;

        $premium_member_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'premium-member',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'key' => $state,
                'value' => $district,
            ),
        );

        $premium_member_query = new WP_Query( $premium_member_args );
        if ( $premium_member_query->have_posts() ):
        while ( $premium_member_query->have_posts() ) : $premium_member_query->the_post();
        $state_value = get_field( 'state'); 
        $district_value = get_field( 'district'
```

[the image says all I want!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V51lZ.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. You need to _show us_ what you tried, not just tell us that you tried “something”, but it didn’t work.

Comment: sorry!! please check now

Comment: You need to use the actual meta field name as the key - right now, you appear to be using one of the values, `18` – I doubt your field is actually _named_ 18? And if you are talking about two different meta fields here, then you need to add _two_ meta queries, one for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT THE ANSWER!!

```
    <?php  
$state = $_GET["state"];
$district = $_GET["district"];
$premium_member_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'premium-member',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'state',
            'value' => $state,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'district',
            'value' => $district,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    )
);
$premium_member_query = new WP_Query( $premium_member_args );
if ( $premium_member_query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $premium_member_query->have_posts() ) : $premium_member_query->the_post();
    ?>
        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h5>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```